# Prove that any subset of six elements of $S=\left\{1,2,...,9 \right\}$ must contain at least two elements whose sum is 10.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

> Prove that any subset of six elements of $S=\left\{1,2,...,9 \right\}$ must contain
>   at least two elements whose sum is 10.

I thought of using the pigeonhole principle, but I can't think of how to write this proof, I can only think of particular cases.

Let's say I have the subset $A\subset S$, $A=\left\{1,2,3,4,5,6 \right\}$, so there's $6+4=10$, and $5+2+1$ and blah blah blah...

I can't think of a way to "generalize" this... Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Let $S=\{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}$. Suppose 6 integers are chosen from S. Must there be 2 integers whose sum is 15?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456444/let-s-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-suppose-6-integers-are-chosen-from-s-must-t) – same  problem, same solution, only with slightly  different numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a partition $$\{1,9\}, \{2,8\},\{3,7\},\{4,6\}\{5\}$$ So we have 5 sets(houses) and 6 numbers (pigeons)...

Perhaps this:

If we have set with first $2n-1$ elements than every set with $n$ elements have a pair such that their sum is $2n$